# What is this electro mechanical sensor from a washing machine?

Tags: identification, water, pressure

I am taking apart an old (2010) washing machine as a passtime, perhaps some day assemble a garden watering device out of the parts. What would the pictured device be? The white tube was sealed against the washing cylinder. Unfortunately I do not remember top or bottom. The black hose is tough with tiny internal diameter.

Terminals:

- no marking - blue wire
- 2 - unused
- μ - grey wire
- 185 4 - twin brown wire
- 3 - unused

Markings:

```
1-3 16A
1-2 10A
TÜV 
250VAC
KS-2
1-6 2A
SSLOG
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's a water level pressure switch.

Clues:

- One inlet port.
- large diameter allows for large diaphragm which will generate enough force to operate a switch even at very low pressure differential relative to atmospheric.
- It looks these [these](https://duckduckgo.com/?va=p&t=hc&q=washing+machine+pressure+switch&iax=images&ia=images).